# How to know one curve belongs to another?

Tags: algorithm

I have my `curve A` and my `curve B` who is actually part of `curve A`. Now I wish for an algorithm that can identify this belongingness.

A curve here is defined as a series of `2D-(x, y)` points. The `x` value does not mean too much to the belongingness determination. So we are free to left/right shift the curves, if that helps. **What matters most is the shape** and then the `y` value. (That is, the curve may also be moved up/down, but only when necessary)

I have tried searching this on Google, but ended up with no useful information on this. I don't even know the keywords for this problem. Could anyone direct me on this?

P.S. I know (I think so) about Dynamic Time Warping (DTW). AFAIK it identifies two similar curves of different lengths, but not points out the belongingness.

Comment: How do you represent a curve? Is it a formula, or a finite set of points, or what?

Comment: @Beta Sorry for being unclear. Please see Para2 in edited question.

Comment: So, for curve B, you compute the diffs between successive points (x2 - x1, y2 - y1), (x3 - x2, y3 - y2) and do the same for curve A. Now you're just looking for a sequence within a larger sequence.

Answer (score 4):

If the curve can be translated (i.e. moved without rotation) then what does *not* change is the difference between adjacent points. So instead of a list of N points  p<sub>k</sub> = (x<sub>k</sub>, y<sub>k</sub>), we have a list of N-1 vectors d<sub>k</sub> = (x<sub>k+1</sub>-x<sub>k</sub>, y<sub>k+1</sub>-y<sub>k</sub>). Now all we have to do is check whether the B list is contained in the A list, which is trivial.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed one way of doing it. One follow-up question: since A and B are not identical, when we say "B belongs to A" we actually mean that "B is very similar to part of A". So B list will not be contained in the list A, but very similar to that part of A. So how can I take this "similarity" instead of "identicalness" into consideration? Any existing method ?

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: That *completely* changes the problem. Similarity is a matter of degree, so there will be no perfect answer. I suspect the best approach will be some kind of least-squares fitting; I'll have to sleep on it.

Comment: least-squares fitting and then?